# How to change the order of creation/restoring managed beans?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have a complex problem with order of 'JSF bean life cycle actions'.

I have two beans with different scopes. The first, let's call it, `managerBean` is *session* scope bean. The second one, `someBean` has *view* scope (`someBean` really is many different beans). `ManagerBean` takes some action once per page loading and few others view scope beans are using the results of this action in their constructors.

Everything was working just fine until I've started getting forms IDs in xhtml files from java beans. Now action from `managerBean` is taken ***after*** `someBean` is created and I'm getting expected result only when the page is reloaded (on refresh, so `someBean` is using the first results of `ManagerBean` work).

This is how it looks like now:

```
<!-- mainTemplate is a main templete of the page which is rendered once
     per page view (every other actions are taken via ajax). This is a place
     of ManagerBean work after re rendering the page -->
<ui:composition template="/mainTemplate.xhtml"> 
    <ui:define name="mainContent">

        <h:form id="#{someBean.formID}">
            some inputs
        </h:form>

        (...)
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

So when form id was constant String everything worked like I want and now it doesn't. It looks like JSF must calculate ID first and take any other after this (including `ManagerBean` action).

My question is: Is there a way to change this situation?
If something isn't clear enought, please ask. I was trying to simplify the problem because it has many factors. Maybe all my thinking is wrong (the way I want to take some action per page and some actions after it).

Any help will be good!

Comment: As form id is constant, Why you need to call them from ManagedBean?

Comment: Very good question! Thing is it's not dynamic, but we need it to handling error popups (new stuff in soft) and it was very convenient to use it that way. Maybe it is stupid, but I don't like keeping such a string constans in many places (here: in xhtml & bean). So it is getting from beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` (and `binding`) attribute of a JSF UI component is evaluated during view build time. The view build time is that moment when the XHTML source code is turned into a JSF UI component tree. All other attributes of a JSF UI component like `value` and all events like `preRenderView` are evaluated/executed *after* the view build time, usually during view render time (when the JSF UI component tree needs to produce HTML output). This is not something which you can change by just turning a setting or so. It's just the way how JSF works. You can't render something which isn't built yet. You can only change this by writing code the right way.

I can't think of any real world scenario why you need to make the ID attribute dynamic like this. If it were inside a `<c:forEach>`, or part of dynamic component generation, then okay, but this seems just to be a static form. So I would in first place recommend to forget it and just hardcode the ID in the view and rely on other variables (perhaps a hidden input field? depends all on concrete functional requirement which isn't mentioned anywhere in the question nor guessable based on the code posted so far).

If you really need to make it dynamic, then you need to split the `formID` property off from the view scoped bean and move it to a different and independent bean, perhaps an application scoped one.

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense) - component's `id` attribute has same lifecycle as JSTL tags

Comment: **BalusC** you are helpful as always! Like I said in answer to _Masud's_ comment: IDs were hardcoded but we needed to know them in beans for new global error handling (we thought it was the simpliest solution). I wanted to know if it goes in good directions. But saying that keeping IDs in beans is bad practise is enought for me (abandoning this idea was already one of the ways we considered). Thank you very much!